# RGB to Hex Code

Tags: javascript

I'm currently making a RGB to Hex converter and have run into a problem. If, for example, `rgb(9,9,9)` was entered, it would output as `#999` instead of `#090909`. This only seems to be a problem for values 0 through to 9 (though 0 isn't a problem).

My current code:

```
c = type.slice(4).split(','); // type would be 'rgb(9,9,9)'
c[2] = c[2].substring(0, c[2].length - 1);

var s = '#';
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
  c[i] = +c[i]
  s += c[i].toString(16);
  console.log(s);
}
```

As you can see, I do not have a separate input for red, green and blue. I wanted to be just able to input the full colour. I tested this in the javascript console as my page isn't ready yet but shouldn't matter at the moment. I tested it entering `rgb(255,255,255)` and it successfully had the output of `#ffffff`.

If someone could help me out in getting this to work. Thanks.

Comment: Couldn't you just put in a 0 if the rgb number is only 1 digit long? e.g. if(i<10){ i = "0" + i}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your value is smaller than 16 (= 0x10). If it is, add a zero in front:

```
s += (c[i] < 16 ? "0" : "") + c[i].toString(16);
```

Comment: Well ain't that simple. Works too! Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The following will do to the RGB to hex conversion:

```
  function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

alert( rgbToHex(0, 51, 255) ); // #0033ff
```

**OR**

You can use below code also. In following function,if the specified color string is already hex, it returns the string. If it’s in rgb format, it converts it to hex.

```
    function colorToHex(color) {
    if (color.substr(0, 1) === '#') {
        return color;
    }
    var digits = /(.*?)rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(color);

    var red = parseInt(digits[2]);
    var green = parseInt(digits[3]);
    var blue = parseInt(digits[4]);

    var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
    return digits[1] + '#' + rgb.toString(16);
};

colorToHex('rgb(120, 120, 240)')
```

Comment: perfect solution for what i needed :D

Answer (score 1):

**Try this simple js function:**

```
function rgb2hex(rgb_color) {
    var output = [];
    var slots = rgb_color.trim().match(/^rgba?\(([0-9]+),([0-9]+),([0-9]+)(,[0-9]+)?\)$/i);
    if (slots instanceof Array) {
        for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
            var _hex = parseInt(slots[x], 10).toString(16) + "";
            output.push(_hex.length == 2 ? _hex : "0" + _hex)
        }
    }
    return "#" + output.join("");
}

console.log(rgb2hex("rgb(9,9,9)"));
```